# Angular - Building form based on user input

Tags: html, angular, dom, angular-forms

I'm building a web form that is supposed to be dynamic.
When a user selects an option from a list, the next form inputs are generated based on his input.
For instance:

```
<mat-form-field>
     <mat-select placeholder="Type" [(ngModel)]="row.Type" (change)="TypeChosen(row.Type, row)">
         <mat-option [value]="0">Treatment</mat-option>
         <mat-option [value]="1">Travel</mat-option>
         <mat-option [value]="2">Medication</mat-option>
         <mat-option [value]="3">Equipment</mat-option>
     </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

If he selects Type 'Treatment', he gets another selection input with some options with a few other inputs, and if he selects a different Type, he gets different options and other inputs.

I understand that I need to dynamically generate HTML content, and maybe a dynamic component.
What is the best approach to do this in an easy way?

Comment: dynamic component will do...because angular not allows to put dynamic html from your ts file (you can do that with domsanatizer)

Comment: Why don't you use `*ngIf` directive ? This is how dinamically html works in angular, with some other directives which they also include `*` in their syntax.

Comment: @PranayRana Since I'm not experienced, an example would help me. Thanks.

Comment: @Korte There are too many options and conditional flows, that ```*ngIf``` complicates the code and makes it messy.

Comment: I still would recommend using *ngIf combined with short functions that contain the conditions. Something like *ngIf="shouldIshowX()", with shouldIshowX() { return condition1 && condition2 && !condition3 }

Answer (score 8):

I'd suggest creating a component for each sub-form and then `*ngIf` them based on the selected option, like so:

```html
<!-- component.html -->

<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select placeholder="Type" [(ngModel)]="row.Type" (change)="onTypeChosen(row.Type, row)">
    <mat-option [value]="0">Treatment</mat-option>
    <mat-option [value]="1">Travel</mat-option>
    <mat-option [value]="2">Medication</mat-option>
    <mat-option [value]="3">Equipment</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

<my-treatment-component *ngIf="type === 0" [someInput]="'some value'"></my-treatment-component>
<my-travel-component *ngIf="type === 1" [somethingElse]="true"></my-travel-component>
<my-medication-component *ngIf="type === 2" (someOutput)="onMedicationOutput($event)"></my-medication-component>
<my-equipment-component *ngIf="type === 3"></my-equipment-component>
```

If you already have something holding your Type selection, you can bind that to the `*ngIf`s instead. If not, create a field in your controller class and hold the selected type in there.

```ts
// component.ts

public type: number | null = null;

public onTypeChosen(type: number, row): void {
  this.type = type;
}
```

If your sub-forms have parts that are re-usable (or are basically the same, sans configuration), it's generally a good practice to extract the re-usable code into components in and of themselves and compose them together.

Hope this helps a little :-)

Answer (score 3):

To Add the options dynamically, angular provide ( `*ngFor` ).

```
<mat-form-field>
     <mat-select placeholder="Type" [(ngModel)]="row.Type" (change)="TypeChosen(row.Type, row)" *ngFor="let option of options; let i = index">
         <mat-option (click)="updateOptions(option)" [value]="{{i}}">option.text</mat-option>
     </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

---

in your controller .ts

```
private options = [];

private initOptions(){
this.options = [
{text:'Treatment' , possibleOptionsRelates:[text:'possible1']},
{text:'Travel' , possibleOptionsRelates:[text:'possible12']},
{text:'Medication' , possibleOptionsRelates:[text:'possible13']}];
}
private updateOptions(option){
     this.options.push(...option.possibleOptionsRelates);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It's a good start, but it's more complicated than that, because I'm not adding only one ```mat-select``` with options, but a few other inputs, which some are added for Treatment, some for Travel etc.

Comment: are other mat-select sharing the same options ??

Comment: No. Each has it's own condition and options.